# Joomla 4.4.1 / Joomla 5 getting current logged user

Tags: joomla

I am upgrading from Joomla 3 to Joomla 5 and can't get data about currently logged user. In joomla 3 it was pretty simple.
I am runing testing site on XAMPP

- Apache 2.4.58
- MariaDB 10.4.32
- PHP 8.1.25 (VS16 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR
- phpMyAdmin 5.2.1
- OpenSSL 1.1.1p
- ADOdb 518a
- Mercury Mail Transport System v4.63 (not included in the portable version)
- FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41 (not included in the portable version)
- Webalizer 2.23-04 (not included in the portable version)
- Strawberry Perl 5.32.1.1 Portable

Joomla 3

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', '../');
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/framework.php';

// Create the Application
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');


$general = JFactory::getUser();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($general->id);
$groups =  $general->groups;
$username =  $general->username;
$name =  $general->name;
$id = $general->id;
?>
```

Joomla 5

```
$joomla_directory = "../";
define('_JEXEC', 1);
//define('JPATH_BASE','../');
define('JPATH_BASE', (isset($joomla_directory)) ? $joomla_directory : __DIR__ );
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . 'includes/framework.php';

$class_name             =  new \Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication;
$session_alias          = 'session.web';
$session_suffix         = 'web.site';


use Joomla\CMS\User\CurrentUserTrait;



$user = $this->getCurrentUser()
```

I am no expert on this so please excuse if there is obvious stupidity :)

Comment: Can anyone help?